# Do I need two agents in dialogflow if I want to build Appointment Scheduler bot and Google Calendar bot?

Tags: dialogflow-es

I want to build one bot with two skills which can make appointment for me and make notification for me. It is similar with following two videos:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oU88sHd6ilE&t=2s
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4_MvIf_ULgc

do I need two agents? Because I need two gcp projects for this agents (https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/multi-project) , how to manage them? I don't believe we need two project to finish one chatbot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short Answer:**

You don't need two agents in Dialogflow for the functionalities you require.

**Detailed Answer:**

The whole point of Dialogflow is to try to identify what is the user's intention and then act on it.

So if you create 1 agent and then create multiple Intents

1. First one for Making an Appointment
2. Second one for Making a notification

Then you train the agent with examples for each intents *(Using entities etc.)*

When the user says something to the bot, Dialogflow will understand what the user means (*Detects the corresponding Intent*) and then you can do the business logic for each intent

What's important is the way you train the bot, making sure your training phrases do not overlap from one intent to another